# Get values from multiple radio group in angular

Tags: json, angular, angular-reactive-forms

I want to get selected radio button value then create an object to send to database, I have working example here https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-1frcbc .I  got what i expected object like this

```
{
    lessonCode: 'test',
    answers: [
            {
        questionCode : 'question-1',
        optionCode : 'option-2'
        },
            {
        questionCode : 'question-2',
        optionCode : 'option-3'
        },
    ]       
}
```

but there is an error ERROR like

```
Error: Error trying to diff 'Option 2'. Only arrays and iterables are allowed
```

I believe there is something wrong in here

```
  <input type="radio" id="{{option.order}}" [(ngModel)]="question.options" value="{{option.code}}" name="{{question.order}}">
```

can someone help me? any thoughts would be helpful

EDIT

i know that `question.options` can't assign to `ngModel` if i change it to something like `option.order` .I'm not getting object like what i expected above, if i change to something like that.

I'm pretty sure i need to change this code

```
  getJsonResult() {
    let answer: any;
    let data = {
      lessonCode: "test",
      answers: this.data.questions.map(x => {
        return {
          questionCode: x.code,
          optionCode: x.options
        };
      })
    };
    this.submitData = data;
    console.log(JSON.stringify(this.submitData))
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

i accidentally change my code to something like this

```
    return {
      questionCode: x.code,
      status: x.options.code
    };
```

and in the html like this

```
<input type="radio" id="{{option.order}}" [(ngModel)]="question.options.code" value="{{option.code}}" name="{{question.order}}">
```

and it works and give me the same result, hope this will help someone